# Running parallel_tests for Ruby-Capybara not working

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, parallel-testing

Running a simple login automation test using Capybara. No database is used.
I am trying to use parallel_test gem to invoke multiple test sessions at the same time (chrome browser) using the following command

`parallel_rspec -n 2`

two browsers are invoked but only the first one is launched with the correct URL and the second one is simply blank. Also, the login and password values are concatenated twice (data collision) in the first browser input fields.

Framework - Non-rails. Ruby with capybara

```
config/database.yml

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: test_db<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  encoding: utf8
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```

spec_file - 1

```
describe '' do
 it '' do
  ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] = ''
 end
end
```

spec_file - 2

```
describe '' do
 it '' do
  ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] = '2'
 end
end
```

both spec files are in the same folder

There is very little guidance for nonrails setup. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way we can reproduce your problem? It's very difficult to give pointers when all the information we have is "it doesn't work".

Comment: In https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests#setup-for-non-rails it explains that ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] will be set differently for each test instance launched by parallel_text - you need to use that to configure each testing instance differently - show the configuration settings code where you're using that.

Comment: Edited the question with details @ThomasWalpole